# iptables rule to snat port and ip on AWS instance

Tags: iptables

Hopefully somebody can help me or at least get me pointed in the correct direction.
I've got a NAT instance on AWS which is providing outbound traffic for a host to the internet.  This works just fine.
What I need to do is take an arbitrary port (lets use port 26 as an example) from the HOST and on the NAT machine, translate that to appear to come from the NAT machine on port 25.
This rule is what I'm trying to make work:

iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 26 -j SNAT --to 172.17.2.125:25

The rule currently will happily change the IP address but leaves the outgoing port unaltered.

A redirect will happily change the port but won't change the source IP (so it won't leave the box on the correct public IP).

I've thought about using something like pfSense or some other firewall product which I think might be able to do this but it seems like overkill for something which seems "simple".  I've tried googling like crazy but I must be googling the wrong terms... I've tried the "transparent proxy" but that didn't seem to work either.

Updating this a bit

HOST          = 172.17.1.125, outbound SMTP connection via port 26
NAT           = 172.17.2.126
DESTINATION   = 216.1.2.3 port 25 (standard SMTP port)

What is needed is to have

HOST (internal) -> NAT -> DESTINATION

To make this happen correctly, NAT server must translate port 26 traffic
to 172.17.2.126 port 25.

Comment: Could you explain *why* you need to appear the connection coming from port 25? SNAT works by re-assigning port numbers so different source addresses will have different ports (otherwise it can't track the connection, and restore the correct IP address for incoming packets). So you'll be able to map at most one particular source with one particular port to the NAT IP and port 25. (Also, you need `--sport`, because it NATs the source port).

Comment: The connection needs to appear to be coming from the ip address 172.17.2.125 (so that AWS routes it our the correct elastic IP) but the destination port must be 25 (this is an outbound SMTP connection so the receiving servers are all listening on port 25)  Also, `--sport` won't match because the incoming connection which is being NATted is coming in on port 26 and that appears to the NAT instance as the destination.  I've tried using `--sport` in a logging rule and it doesn't get hit

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. Am I missing something? If the *destination* port must be 25, then the source port doesn't matter (the listening servers don't care which port the incoming connection comes from), so you can just do normal SNAT/MASQERADE.

Comment: I've updated the question a bit so as to hopefully make it clear.  The source port matters because that is what drives the IP on which it will submit out via.  Port 26 should go out 172.17.2.126 port 25, port 27 goes out 172.17.2.127:25, port 27 = 172.17.2.128:25, etc.  
AWS requires big instance sizes for lots of IPs (even internal) but our MTA software can send SMTP traffic via a large collection of alternate ports.  This way we can have many email servers feeding a NAT instance which has all the public IPs

Comment: I just tested (with `nc` and namespaces, and `tcpdump` to verify), and it happily translates both source IP and source port for me, both for `--sport` and `--dport` to determine the source ip. Of course, when using the destination port to choose source ip, you can't change the destination port to something canonical like 25, that would require DNAT...  No idea what goes wrong on your side. I run kernel 4.8.5, if this matters.

Comment: Would you post your iptables commands so I can see what you used?

Comment: Would you post your iptables commands so I can see what you used? _Of course, when using the destination port to choose source ip, you can't change the destination port to something canonical like 25, that would require DNAT_ the documentation [link](https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/NAT-HOWTO-6.html) seems to imply that you can change the port.  Is there somewhere else which says this can't work?  I was also thinking about using a DNAT and a SNAT rule together to get the desired effect but couldn't get it to hit both rules (if we think this might work, I can try harder!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get somebody who could help me out with this problem.  Here are the rules we used to map ports through to outgoing IP addresses in AWS:

First, you have to have this running through a NAT instance to make it work.  There are lots of resources on how to configure that.

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 27 -j MARK  --set-mark 27
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 27 -j DNAT --to :25
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m mark --mark 27 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.11
```

Answer (score 1):

Test setup: Two network namespaces `ns0` (your external mail server), `ns1` (your HOST). Main network namespace (your NAT) does forwarding and nat. Two veth-pairs connecting namespaces:

```
ns0 --->     <------ main ns ----->     <--- ns1
veth0b   --- veth0a      veth1a     --- veth1b
10.0.0.1     10.0.0.254  10.0.1.254     10.0.1.1
```

`tcpdump` on veth0a and veth1a. `nc -k -l -p 9999` listens on port 9999 in `ns0` as "mail server". Client via various `nc` commands in `ns1`. Normal connection, no nat, random source port per default:

```
$ echo foo | nc 10.0.0.1 9999 -q0
veth*a: IP 10.0.1.1.60560 > 10.0.0.1.9999 
veth*a: IP 10.0.0.1.9999 > 10.0.1.1.60560
```

Match on source port (I added `-s` to all matches to avoid surprises, but it also works without `-s`):

```
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o veth0a -s 10.0.1.1/32 -p tcp --sport 8001 -j SNAT --to 10.0.1.81:9900
$ echo foo | nc 10.0.0.1 -p 8001 9999 -q0
veth1a: IP 10.0.1.1.8001 > 10.0.0.1.9999 
veth0a: IP 10.0.1.81.9900 > 10.0.0.1.9999
veth0a: IP 10.0.0.1.9999 > 10.0.1.81.9900
veth1a: IP 10.0.0.1.9999 > 10.0.1.1.8001
```

Match on destination port (doesn't reach "server", because rules can't rewrite destination port):

```
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o veth0a -s 10.0.1.1/32 -p tcp --dport 7002 -j SNAT --to 10.0.1.82:9900
$ echo bar | nc 10.0.0.1 7002 -q0
veth1a: IP 10.0.1.1.38614 > 10.0.0.1.7002 
veth0a: IP 10.0.1.82.9900 > 10.0.0.1.7002
veth0a: IP 10.0.0.1.7002 > 10.0.1.82.9900
veth1a: IP 10.0.0.1.7002 > 10.0.1.1.38614
```

As you can see, both source address and source port get translated fine. In **S**NAT (source nat), you can only translate **source** address and port, that's what the S means, and that's what the documentation you linked says. Conversely, in DNAT, you can translate **destionation** address and port. SNAT happens in POSTROUTING (must be on `veth0a` in this setup), DNAT in PREROUTING (must be on `veth1a` in this setup). So you can't combine both in one rule, and you can't do a DNAT after SNAT, because PREROUTING happens before POSTROUTING.

I am getting the impression that what you really want to do is to access various mail servers, but control the **source** address they see you under by replacing the canonical 25 port with other **destination** ports. For example, `mail.xxx.com:26` should contact `mail.xxx.com:25` coming from one address, and `mail.xxx.com:27` should contact `mail.xxx.com:25` coming from another address. (I really do hope this is not connected to sending spam mail...) So the source port doesn't matter, the given destination port determines source address, and the destination port should be changed back to 25. Is this correct? If yes, that can't be done easily on Linux due to the way nat works.

And if you can convince you don't need it for spam mail, I can think of two better options (depending on what your MTA software can do).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation helps quite a bit.  I'm pretty new to iptables so I misunderstood the documentation :)  You basically have it exactly correct on what we are attempting to do (minus the spam part, each customer gets an ip so we can manage reputation).  We are moving our system to AWS and we are limited unlike in our own data centres (where we have our own FWs and we can have as many internal IPs as we want).  To get more internal IPs, AWS requires you to increase your instance size and I've been trying to reduce the complexity.  I've love to hear some other options!